# Is there a way to force the summary line to the bottom of the result set when using GROUPING SETS?

Tags: sql, t-sql

The following works perfectly, except the summary line get calculated in the ORDER BY clause and ends up at the top of the result set. Is there anyway of forcing it to the bottom without removing the ORDER BY clause?

```
select 
  col1,sum(col2),sum(col3) as [Count] FROM #tmpTbl 
where 
  col3>0 
group by 
  grouping sets((col1),()) 
order by 
  [Count] desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how your query is actually running correctly, but you need to add a condition to your `Order By` clause:

```
Select      col1,
            sum(col2),
            sum(col3) as [Count] 
From        #tmpTbl 
Where       [Count] > 0 
Group by    Grouping Sets((col1),()), 
Order by    Grouping(col1),
            [Count] desc
```

Though, your query without the syntax errors would be like this:

```
Select      col1,
            sum(col2),
            sum(col3) as [Count] 
From        #tmpTbl 
Group by    Grouping Sets((col1),())
Having      Sum(col3)  > 0 
Order by    Grouping(col1),
            [Count] desc
```

Essentially, `Grouping(column)` returns 1 or 0 depending on if the current row is being grouped.  You can just pass in any of the columns in the set to get this result.  In this case, `col1`.  Everything that is not the grouping row will get a 0, and the grouping row will get a 1, causing the summary row to be sorted last.

And just for fun: if you want the summary column to display 'Total'...

```
Select      Case When Grouping(col1) = 1 Then 'Total' Else Cast(col1 As Varchar(5)) End As Col1,
            sum(col2),
            sum(col3) as [Count] 
From        #tmpTbl 
Group by    Grouping Sets((col1),())
Having      Sum(col3)  > 0 
Order by    Grouping(col1),
            [Count] desc
```

Comment: Fixed the syntax issue. Cutting and Pasting here and there. Thanks for keeping me honest.